# How install PHP 5.4, mod_security and mod_evasive together without conflict

Tags: amazon-ec2, httpd, mod-security

I need create webserver with PHP 5.4, and install mod_security and mod_evasive. But when I try to join the php 5.4 and the mods on an EC2 server, it returns an error of conflict between the versions httpd. I followed the tutorial [link](http://tutorial.centos.com.my/?p=69) trying to do the right way. But even this with php 5.3. My application works with many filter_input. How can I install PHP 5.4 (minimum), mod_security and mod_evasive together without conflict?

I switched to Ubuntu or Linux can continue with EC2?

Comment: I have the same problem too, I will let you know if I find a fix :)